# Spring MVC : How to access a modelAndView XML object in Javascript ?

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc

I have a String variable, containing XML. I added it to my model with modelAndView.addObject(...). Now, how can I access this object in Javascript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that in your controller you did something like

`modelAndView.addObject("someValue", someValue)`.

In your JSP, you can do this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var someValue = "${someValue}";
</script>
```

And then you can use this variable in your JS.

Comment: modelAndView.addObject("someValue", someValue);

Comment: when try to get someValue it is giving '${someValue}' not value

Comment: Sorry, what if you try with " instead of ' ? Just edited my answer consequently.

Comment: it not getting complete value it is xml string it having only half of that.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming you want to access Model attribute*
Using   `<c:set>` like

```
<c:set var="myData" value="${myObject.data}" />
```

and then you can use this var in js using `${myData}`.
For example in jQuery selector

```
<script>
    $("#${myData}").val('foo');
</script>
```

Comment: the mapping field contain THE DATA how can get from there

Comment: @Amit: Check my edit. Provide some more inputs like which object you are passing and which field you want to acees.

Comment: @Amit: I just added for example. Check my edit and provide some information.

Comment: i am passing a xml string if i have that in a div on jsp its format is change i do not put it jsp i want that xml string on js so can dosomething there.