# How to use variable sent from modelmap in js render iteration loop

Tags: java, javascript, spring, web, jsrender

I am sending a variable in a modelmap from java controller to a view like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someAction", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(ModelMap model) {
  model.addAttribute("myVariable",true);
  return "myView"; //returns the view 
}
```

Now i have this view file "myView.html" where i've used jsrender and that has a data and i iterate it like given below.Also i need to use the "myVariable" inside that iteration like this :

```
<script id="iterData" type="text/x-jsrender">
{^{for #data}}
    {{if Name != '-'}}
            {{if Age =='20'}}
               {{if myVariable??}} //This part doesnt work.I wonder how to use it here

                    //Some codes                     

               {{/if}}

            {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
{{/for}}
</script>
```

Can anyone help me how i could use the "myvariable" inside the jsrender iteration??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC : How to access a modelAndView XML object in Javascript ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235319/spring-mvc-how-to-access-a-modelandview-xml-object-in-javascript)

Comment: No.We cant use it that way in jsrender.We can use like {{if myVariable??}} outside the for loop in jsrender.But it doesnot work inside the for loop.Wondering how to use it inside the jsrender for loop

Comment: So I assume model has an array property that you are passing to the   iterData template. How are you calling the iterData template? Can you show that line of code? It will then be easier to answer your question...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your use of `{{for #data}}` - hence my question in a comment.

But one way of passing in variables to nested template contexts is as by passing in a template variable from the outer context to the inner contexts:

For example, if `myVariable` is a property on any outer context, you can write:

```
{{!-- myVariable and someArray are properties on the data at this level--}}

{{for someArray ~myVar=myVariable}} 
  {{if Name != '-'}}
    {{if Age =='20'}}
      {{if ~myVar}}
         ...                     
      {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/if}}
{{/for}}
```